# Second Image publisher has reset filename as '--ros-args' instead of rtsp stream, why?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using ros2 and image_publisher, I have two image_publisher nodes to convert two rtsp streams to ros2 image streams, but the second stream does not work.
I am using following launch file:

```
import os
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node


def generate_launch_description():
    base_config_path = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('project'), 'config')
    image_publisher_config0 = os.path.join(base_config_path, "image_publisher0.yaml")
    image_publisher_config1 = os.path.join(base_config_path, "image_publisher1.yaml")
    return LaunchDescription([
        Node(
            package='image_publisher',
            executable='image_publisher_node',
            namespace='cam0',
            parameters=[image_publisher_config0],
        ),
        Node(
            package='image_publisher',
            executable='image_publisher_node',
            namespace='cam1',
            parameters=[image_publisher_config1],
        )
    ])
```

and I'm using following two config files:

```
cam[0/1]/ImagePublisher:
  ros__parameters:
    filename: rtsp://10.11.12.2[0/1]/live_stream
    publish_rate: 25.0
    frame_id: world
```

Now the first stream starts normally and everything works, but the second stream somehow doesn't take the filename parameter. This seems odd, because the configs are exactly the same besides the namespace differences of 0/1.
Node cam0 outputs: Reset filename as `rtsp://10.11.12.20/live_stream` but Node cam1 outputs: `Reset filename as '--ros-args'`.
Why is that and how can I fix it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/369829/second-image-publisher-has-reset-filename-as-%27--ros-args%27-instead-of-rtsp-stream,-why?/) by [Hakaishin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28097/hakaishin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 142 on 2021-01-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was that I forgot to built my package after copying the second config file. Ros really does fail catastrophically when it does. Meaning it doesn't straight out fail, it just tries to do weird stuff instead of telling you whats wrong.

---

Originally posted by [Hakaishin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28097/hakaishin/) with karma: 142 on 2021-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1